# SugarCRM 6.2 - Adding a custom field in user profile

Tags: sugarcrm

Yeah. As the title says, I am tasked with creating custom field in user profile, and sort of hit a wall on this one.  It is a very small customisation, add a  `yearly_target` field to user edit and detail view.

I was happy to stumble on [this article to add a custom field in sugar](http://www.eontek.rs/sugarcrm/add-new-field-into-create-new-user-form/).
Although it's a huge help, it seems to be missing one or 2 minor points.

To have the fields show in edit and detail views, one apparently needs to create and edits `EditView.php` and `EditView.tpl` and `DetailView.php` and `DetailView.tpl`,  except I am not too sure where these files go. The yearly target field shows up in user list view, but not in edit/detail views.  I tried `custom/modules/Users` , `custom/modules/Users/ext` , but changes made in the templates (static html changes) have no effect.

Anyone know where these files should go?

Thanks SO'ers!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the eontek site has (re)moved all the snippets pages. I always get just the front page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should go in the custom/modules/Users/ directory. Do make sure you change the references inside the EditView.php and DetailView.php files to reference the templates you have in the custom/modules/Users/ directory instead of the default ones in the modules/Users/ directory.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the step I was missing.  Thanks friend.